# Visual Studio cannot open source file inspite of setup

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, googlemock

I'm running VS2015 on Windows 10 and I'm having issues with include directories. I have setup the *Additional Include Directories* in *C/C++ -> General* and *Include Directories* in *VC++ Directories* to point to the right path (F:\boost_1_61_0). I keep getting the "Cannot open source file" error. If I move the cursor to the include statement the full include path in the *Definition* bar points to the correct address. This also happens when working with *Google Mock*. All the core and STL includes work just fine.

I've stripped down the code to try and just get it to work on this basic Boost test code:

```
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    typedef std::istream_iterator<int> in;

    std::for_each(
    in(std::cin), in(), std::cout << (_1 * 3) << " " );
}
```

I've successfully built this code using Netbeans by adding the additional include directory to the project without any issues, so its not a file access issue. The compiler used from Netbeans was G++, but from VS I used MSVC and tried ICP with the same results.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you try right-clicking on the `#include` line and choosing "open document <...>" and seeing if it opens the right file?

Comment: I get the error "not found in current source file's directory or in build system paths", which is strange seeing as how its in the project's configuration properties.

Comment: To be clear - you definitely have a file at F:\boost_1_61_0\boost\lambda\lambda.hpp ?Also, when VS displayed the error, did you see your "F:\boost_1_61_0" in the list of include directories?

Comment: There is in fact a file F:\boost_1_61_0\boost\lambda\lambda.hpp, if I open a cmd and enter *type F:\boost_1_61_0\boost\lambda\lambda.hpp* it displays the contents of the file. The error message VC throws when I right click and select open document does not show the boost directory listed.

Comment: *Additional Include Directories* definitely has the entry for F:\boost_1_61_0. In the *Description* box if I hit the *Go* button VS manages to open the *lambda.hpp* document inside of a new tab.

Comment: One more thing to try - if the directory isn't showing up, possibly you have the include directories only set in different configuration to the one you are compiling with. The current configuration is displayed in the build output window like `------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------` and is also shown in drop down boxes in the project properties screen. Make sure they match.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *The Dark* states above: make sure you check that the build properties match.